# Regular expression range expression in PHP

Tags: php, regex

How do I express a range of 400-5000?  I know that a range of 3-8 would be [3-8]

For the 400-5000 one it is only reading as 0-5.....what am I missing here?
Thank you

Comment: The range specs would be `{3,8}` and `{400,5000}`, resp.

Comment: You could at least post the regex you tried.

Comment: [4-9][0-9][0-9]|[1-5][0-9][0-9][0-9]

Comment: Why regex? `if($n >= 400 && $n <= 5000) { ... }`

Comment: Relevant and recent: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285733/should-give-me-a-regex-that-does-x-questions-be-closed

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in several ways.

My first suggestion is `^(5000)|(([1-4][0-9]|[4-9])[0-9]{2})$`

Can you try? It helps you?